# How to check for empty document.paragraph values extracted from doc.table?

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I am using the win32com Python module to target a Word .doc table and then extract all Sentences/ListParagraphs from it.

I am able to successfully get the all my content using `doc.Paragraphs`. I then try to run..

EDITED:

`doc = word.Documents.Open(path)`
`list = doc.Paragraphs`
`for x in list:`
`if str(x.Style) == "Normal" and x != "":`
`# do stuff`

this does not detect empty/whitespaced Lists and Paragraphs. I also tried using
`x.isspace()` to check for white space but it always returned `False`.

I have had a run in with `\r\n\t\x07\x0b` characters before, which seem to be extracted in COM class objects. They cause all sorts of weird issues when converting them to strings. Could it be something similar?

Thanks

Comment: `if str(x.Style) == "Normal" and not "":` is a nonsense line. The first part is okay(-ish -- why does the style name matter?) but the truthy/falsy part `not ""` will just always return `True`, and, due to the `and`, do nothing, positive or negative. Are you forgetting something there?

Comment: Ah -- `x.isspace()` always fails because `x` is never a space, it's a *paragraph*. The list you get returned is a list of paragraphs so you want to check `text = x.Range.Text`.

Comment: Depending on the ```x.Style``` I perform certain tasks. I.e if its a Bulleted List, do X. If it is has a Normal style, do Y. I could be forgetting something, but the main goal is to check for the style and if the paragraph is empty i.e ```""```